# How to bind value of property to collection in Mybatis?

Tags: java, mybatis

I have a custom sql called `addCollectionToAndConditionWhenNotEmpty` as Follows

```
<sql id="addCollectionToAndConditionWhenNotEmpty">
    <if test="collections != null and collections.isEmpty()">
        AND <if test="andNot = true">NOT</if> ${field}
        IN <foreach item="item" collection="collections" open="(" separator="," close=")">#{item}</foreach>
    </if>
</sql>
```

So, I want that.

```
<include refid="addCollectionToAndConditionWhenNotEmpty">
    <property name="field" value="TABLE.column"/>
    <property name="collections" value="data.idList"/>
</include>
```

However, such an error occurs.

```
nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'collections' not found. Available parameters are [param1, option]"
```

How to bind value of property to collection in Mybatis?

---

(+) If use it like this, it will be executed but I do not want it.

```
<bind name="collections" value="params.idList"/>
<include refid="addCollectionToAndConditionWhenNotEmpty">
    <property name="field" value="CNTT.cntt_no"/>
    <property name="collections" value="collections"/>
</include>
```